# How correctly is the request sent from the locale?

Tags: flutter, dart, get, strapi

I used strapi to write queries. I checked it on postman, using "localhost" instead of IP, everything is fine. However, when I sent a request from flutter, I got an error, which I managed to avoid by using my ip instead of "localhost". But also through postman now error 502, the same error if sent via flutter

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async {
          var url = 'http://мой.айпи.43/api/pelargoniums';
          Map<String,String> headers = {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          };
            final response = await http.get(
              Uri.parse(url),
              headers: headers
            );
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
              print(response.body);
              print('yep');
            } else {
              print(response.statusCode);
            }

        }, child: Text('wewewewew'))
```

Please tell me what is my problem and how to fix it?

Comment: What the error? Please attach the error.

Comment: 502 Bad Gateway
nginx

Comment: Or if using localhost - Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 55708

Answer (score 0):

When testing on a mobile device (Android , iOS) , you must connect within the same Wi-Fi network to use IP communication. If it is used as a web, Windows, or mac program, it can be used.

Comment: I am using android emulator

Comment: are you access android internet permision? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting

Comment: Yep
My AndroidManifest.xml (main) - `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.pelargonium">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

Comment: what is your url style ?  for example : var url = 'http://111.111.111.111:8080/test';

Comment: My ip address looks like '111.111.111.11/api /test'
I don't post anything after

Comment: what is port number?

Comment: I don't know, I've never dealt with a server ((((

Comment: So how did you create the local server?

Comment: I just use the strapi installation guide(

Comment: write in portnumber for example :  111.111.111.11:1337/api /test

Comment: what is strapi api  get or post ? so run  'http://localhost:1337/api/tests' not running?

Comment: Get. If you use localhost, then it works through postman, but not in the fluter application, because you need to use the IP there

Comment: What if you run it on a real Android device?